# Shell variable evaluating inside while loop

Tags: shell

I am trying to run .sh file to put certificate via keytool command in every jre/lib/security/cacert file described in ~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties file.

But getting error "Keystore parameter must not be empty" in

```
sudo bash -c keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias test-cert -file ./test.cer -keystore ${resultPath};
```

I already tried use eval and "$()" notation - but this failed too. How can I fix that?

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN=deployment\.javaws\.jre\.[0-9]*\.path
FILE=~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
sep='='
trail=lib/security/cacerts

#Traverse file line by line
while read line ; do

  #If line matches pattern
  if printf %s\\n "${line}" | grep -q "${PATTERN}"; then
    case $line in 
      (*"$sep"*)

        #Process line to get path for ../jre/lib/security/cacert file
        after=${line#*"$sep"};
        resultPath=${after%????????}${trail};

        #This fails : ${resultPath} somehow is empty
        sudo bash -c keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias test-cert -file ./test.cer -keystore ${resultPath};

      ;;
      (*)
      ;;
    esac
  fi
done < "$FILE"
```

UPDATE: Running script through bash -vx ./script.sh  show this output:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATTERN=deployment\.javaws\.jre\.[0-9]*\.path
+ PATTERN='deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
FILE=~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
+ FILE=/home/sanya/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
sep='='
+ sep==
trail=lib/security/cacerts
+ trail=lib/security/cacerts

#Traverse file line by line
while read line ; do

  #If line matches pattern
  if printf %s\\n "${line}" | grep -q "${PATTERN}"; then
    case $line in 
      (*"$sep"*)

        #Process line to get path for ../jre/lib/security/cacert file
        after=${line#*"$sep"};
        resultPath=${after%????????}${trail};

        #This fails : ${resultPath} somehow is empty
        sudo keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -alias test -file ./test.cer -keystore ${resultPath};
      ;;
      (*)
      ;;
    esac
  fi
done < "$FILE"
+ read line
+ printf '%s\n' '#deployment.properties'
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' '#Sat Sep 06 10:48:49 MSK 2014'
+ read line
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.modified.timestamp=1409986129309
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ read line
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.version=7.21
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ read line
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.browser.path=/usr/bin/firefox
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' '#Java Deployment jre'\''s'
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' '#Sat Sep 06 10:48:49 MSK 2014'
+ read line
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.javaws.jre.0.registered=true
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.javaws.jre.0.platform=1.7
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.javaws.jre.0.osname=Linux
+ read line
+ grep -q 'deployment.javaws.jre.[0-9]*.path'
+ printf '%s\n' deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
+ case $line in
+ after=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
+ resultPath=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
+ sudo keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -alias test -file ./test.cer -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:  keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:885)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
    ... 5 more
+ read line
```

An error line

```
Enter keystore password:  keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

showing because user should enter password for keystore file, but when this script runs, no prompt about entering password is given. How can I fix that?

Comment: run the script with `bash -vx script` and examine the output

Comment: unfortunatelly, I could only use sh ./script.sh to run script.

Comment: but your "sh-bang" line is `!#/bin/bash`. Did  you try `sh -x ./script.sh` or can't you use that either? Can you edit your script or run a edited copy of it from the /tmp dir? Then add `set -x` above your `sudo` line and `set -x` after that line. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Updated the question with use of bash -vx script. Another issue: user should be asked for password, but instead of that, an error appears.

Answer (score 1):

You should use double quotes to ensure that the variable expansion `${resultPath}` produces a word for the shell.

Thus your critical line should be

```
sudo keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -alias test -file ./test.cer -keystore "${resultPath}";
```

You could also be interested in `:?` or `:-` variable expansion modifiers.

**Note**
It seems to me that the `keytool` program complains that your file is not valid, maybe your issue has nothing with shell programming.